# getting scrollTop to work correctly on ipad (on a popup menu). Currently working in FF

Tags: jquery, ipad, scrolltop

I've been browsing around and it seems that the way to get `scrollTop` to behave properly on the ipad/webkit is to use

`$(jQuery.browser.webkit ? "body": "html").animate({ scrollTop: myTop }, myDur);`

or

`$(document).scrollTop("...");`

The current code I'm using is:

```
openr.onclick = function() {
    $('#statusscroll').scrollTop('#statusscroll');
};
```

`openr` is a button you click to bring up a menu. The `scrollTop` should be applied to it. Currently you open it, scroll down to the bottom>close it>reopen it and the menu is back to the top (reset). This is good and now I need to implement this in Safari for the ipad.

I'm working on Windows 7 and have Safari 5.x downloaded (which seems like absolute garbage for what it's worth) and the scrollTop IS working (and for Firefox too). But yet when I test the above code on the ipad, `scrollTop` does not work properly.

It's not like I can do

`$(document).scrollTop('#statusscroll');` for ipad

**So how do I correctly implement scrollTop for a menu, ON that menu ('#statusscroll' in this case) on the iPad?**